# How to update postgresql json date field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update json date field with value from another column.
I am able to update with the following statement:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET column = column || '{"date_field":"2022-08-25"}' 
where id = 123;
```

When I try to update with value from another column ie:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET json_column = json_column || '{"date_field":column}' 
where id = 123;
```

I would get the following Error.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
> LINE 2: ...DATE table SET json_column = json_column || '{"date_field...
>
> DETAIL:  Token "column" is invalid.
> CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"date_field":column...
> SQL state: 22P02
> Character: 54

The database is PostgreSQL version 10.9.
Could someone point me to where I can find the right syntax?

Comment: Your error does not match the data you show. Where is `"required_date"` from?

Comment: You should add to your question that you are working with `jsonb` type not `json`.

Comment: I fixed error regarding "required_date".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note `||` only works with `jsonb`.

```
\d json_test 
               Table "public.json_test"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id        | integer |           |          | 
 fld_json  | json    |           |          | 
 fld_jsonb | jsonb   |           |          | 


select fld_jsonb from json_test  where id = 2;
      fld_jsonb       
----------------------
 {"one": 1, "two": 2}

update json_test set fld_jsonb = fld_jsonb || jsonb_build_object('id', id) where id = 2 ;
UPDATE 1

select fld_jsonb from json_test  where id = 2;
           fld_jsonb           
-------------------------------
 {"id": 2, "one": 1, "two": 2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I did make the mistake with my description of issue.  I appreciate your prompt answer and feedback.